# Can i override my Custom Block Theme Templates (i.e. index.html, 404.html) just using a Custom Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm starting to develop a Block Theme that will have the same home structure but different content, the end result could be achieved also by overrinding template parts.

So, i'm trying to find a way to override the template or template part from the plugin code alone, with no changes to the theme if i have to change plugins.

I've tried `add_filter( 'page_template' )` which is not even firing and `add_filter( 'theme_page_templates' )` which hasn't fired as well.

I've looked into Wordpress Codex for any hooks that could help me but could find none.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter is what you are looking for.

Here's a code snippet that overwrites the 404 page with a given template, in this case `/templates/your_404_page.php`.

You can replicate this behaviour for essentially any page/template that you need.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_404_template', 99 );
function custom_404_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_404()  ) {
        $new_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/your_404_page.php';
        return $new_template;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: The first argumentof this filter is always: wp-includes/template-canvas.php